# align rotated rectangle figures

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I am including two pdf figures, and the second figure is rotated by 90 degrees.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{a}\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,angle=-90,origin=c]{a}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Because the figure is not square, a rotation of 90 around the centre has the effect of misaligning the upper left corner. I would rather have the figure rotate *and* aligned with its upper left corner to the first figure. Something like that:

[image]

How can I obtain the desired alignment, without modifying the figures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,valign=T]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,angle=-90,valign=T]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

[image]